# How can you format multiple items from a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I can't figure out how to format multiple items without getting an error.
I have researched old and new formatting methods.

I tried `("0:%d 1:%s @ $%.2f ea $%.2f).format` and using `%` instead of `.format`,
This might seem simple, but I am stumped.

```
#how to format each item separately?
print((item['number'], item['name'], (item['price']), item_total))


#this code works
print("Grand total:" + str("${:,.2f}".format(grand_total)))
```

Result:

```
(1, 'itemName', 5.00, 5.00)
Grand total:$5.00
```

Desired Result:

```
1 itemName @ $5.00 ea $5.00   #not working
Grand total: $5.00            #success
```

```
grocery_item = {}
grocery_history = []

stop = False
while not stop:
    item_name = input("Item name:\n")
    quantity = input("Quantity purchased:\n")
    cost = input("Price per item:\n")
    grocery_item = {'name': item_name, 'number': int(quantity), 'price': float(cost)}
    grocery_history.append(grocery_item)
    response = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n")

    if response == 'q':
        stop = True

    grand_total = 0

for item in grocery_history:
    item_total = item['number'] * item['price']
    grand_total += item_total

    print((item['number'], item['name'], (item['price']), item_total))
    print("Grand total:" + str("${:,.2f}".format(grand_total)))
```

Comment: Please add an input we can use to test this. As it sits I have no clue how to solve your problem because you expect us to know the contents of `item` without providing it.

Comment: I've included the small code I am working with. I apologize for leaving out information. I am very new to programming, but very interested in learning.

Comment: I was able to get this to work, I was missing an %. Isn't there a newer way to do this using the .format function? If this question is ridiculous I will just delete it.                         print   ('%d %s @ $%.2f ea $%.2f' % (item['number'], item['name'], (item['price']), item_total))

Comment: I think you got the answer you needed below but if that doesn't cover it or raises a different question feel free to ping me :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how to do it from your second print.

```
item = {'number': 1, 'name' : 'itemName', 'price': 5.00}
item_total = 5.00

print('{} {} @ ${:,.2f} ea ${:,.2f}'.format(item['number'], item['name'], item['price'], item_total))
print('%d %s @ $%.2f ea $%.2f' % (item['number'], item['name'], item['price'], item_total))
print(f"{item['number']} { item['name']} @ ${item['price']:,.2f} ea ${item_total:,.2f}")
```

You do nothing for the first print statement. Just print the values of dict and variable. All three (with the commented one) are giving the same results.

```
1 itemName @ $5.00 ea $5.00
1 itemName @ $5.00 ea $5.00
1 itemName @ $5.00 ea $5.00
```

Comment: Thanks, I kept trying to put {%d} and {%s}. I'm just learning format strings. I didn't think of the empty brackets, and I thought they needed to be indexed.

Comment: `%s` will not use brackets so just put `%s` or `%d`. There are many ways to format. I added one more format setting.

Comment: @ChrisCrank The format is cleaner than `%` because you can do `print(f"{item['number']} { item['name']} @ ${item['price']:,.2f} ea ${item_total:,.2f}")` which the answer above doesn't illustrate but is the advantage of `f` strings. Plus python3's format is more powerful.

Comment: @Lamanus Can you add the `f` string in my comment above to your answer.